# Send mail with attachment CSV showing base64 format

Tags: php, laravel, csv, laravel-5, laravel-6

When i send CSV attachment in mail, showing base64 format  in mail response

```
Mail::send('emails.waitingTime', [], function ($message) use ($email, $subject, $fileName) {
    $message->to($email)->subject($subject)->attach(URL::asset('/'. $fileName))->setContentType('text/csv');
});
```

**Showing in mail**

> --_=_swift_1574330801_b65df1604759f4a281a1fd4aab1b757b_=_ Content-Type: text/csv; name=unifonmitel.csv Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=unifonmitel.csv TGlzdGVkLCBBdmcgd2FpdGluZyB0aW1lCkt1bmRlc3VwcG9ydCwgNi43NjU2MjUKU2FsZ3NzdXBw b3J0LCA1LjUKSVQgU3VwcG9ydCwgMi4yCg== --_=_swift_1574330801_b65df1604759f4a281a1fd4aab1b757b_=_--

Comment: Does your .csv file is proper?

Comment: yes 
i also converter base64 data for testing
Its showing same csv file data

Comment: What is value of `$fileName` ?

Comment: `unifonmitel.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your mail function

```
Mail::send('welcome', [], function ($message) use ($email, $subject, $fileName) {
    $message->to($email)->subject($subject)->attach(URL::asset('/'. $fileName))->setContentType('text/csv');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mail::send('emails.waitingTime', [], function ($message) use ($email, $subject, $fileName) {
    $message->to($email)->subject($subject)->attach(URL::asset('/'. $fileName))->setContentType('text/csv');
});
```

**waitingTime.blade**

```
Add something in blade file
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help you

```
$subject = 'Email Subject';
Mail::send('emails.notification', ['message' => $message], function ($mail) use ($userEmail, $subject) {
    $mail->from('info@domain.com', 'Domain Name');
    $mail->to($userEmail)->subject($subject);
});
```

Comment: I need to send CSV attachment in mail,
please check my question